# Is it possible to change UIView's "center" property inside the overriden touchesEnded method and redraw the view?

Tags: iphone, uiview, touch, center

I want to implement a simple animation based on UIView's center property. I have a simple view and I can drag it (UIView touchesMoved is overriden). The animation should fade slowly like the view is moved under it's own inertia for some time after the user releases it. But for now I want simply to move the view after touch ends. Here is the code I have in touchesEnded:

```
int i;
    for (i=1;i<4;i++)
    {
        self.center = CGPointMake(10*i, 12*i);
        [self setNeedsDisplay];
        usleep(100000);
    }
```

The problem is when I run this, the code is executed nicely but "UIView" changes to late. I changed usleep time and other parameters but the result is the same. It looks like all the "pending changes" in the view are performed only after the overriden touchesEnded is finished.

Is this the right way of implementing such user interface feature or should I look for some other approaches?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the final positions you want your view center to have you could do this with an animation:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:20
                      delay:0
                    options: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn
                 animations:^{
                         youView.center = CGPointMake(newCenterX, newCenterY);
                       }
                       completion:^(BOOL finished){ 
                       }];
```

Comment: Well, in this particular case, i don't know because I want the initial energy of the inertia-movement (right after the user releases UIView) to be defined only by the means of initial conditions (velocity and direction). The code looks like numerical Cauchy problem solver in this case. But I will consider this way. Thanks, EliBud.

Comment: Finally, I got the subject work almost the way i wanted. And actually yes, the built-in animation approach looks much more straightforward in this case. The problem as was already mentioned by Joe concerned with main thread blocking during event handling in touchesEnded. The first workaround, that did what I wanted, was to create two functions in my View class. One of these is called in touchesEnded and it only sleeps in background thread and calls the second function within the main thread (which moves the view). This worked but it doesn't look like a best solution.

Answer (score 0):

If that code is being run inside of touchesEnded you are blocking the main thread and that is why the animation happens all at once when its done. You will need run this loop in the background to update the view over time. When you update the UI remember to always call back to the main thread.

**Some Threading Options:**

[performSelectorInBackground:withObject:](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

[performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

[Grand Central Dispatch](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#featuredarticles/BlocksGCD/_index.html)

[Threading](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/Introduction/Introduction.html)

Comment: Thanks Joe. I've tried performSelectorInBackground but I think I missed something. The documentation says that I should setup the thread environment inside the function from which the selector is passed. I'm working on that. What is "call back" to the main thread?

Comment: Take a look @ EliBud's answer which makes more since to just use the built in animation. By call back to the main thread I meant that when you set a property on a UIView such as the center you want to to that on the main thread and not a background thread.